# What does |1 mean in Docker history

Tags: docker

Given this `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM debian:8.3
ARG TEST=123
RUN echo $TEST
```

What does the `|1` represent in the Docker history?

```
$ docker history 2feee0d8320f
IMAGE               CREATED              CREATED BY                                      SIZE                COMMENT
2feee0d8320f        About a minute ago   |1 TEST=123 /bin/sh -c echo $TEST               0 B
ac4872d0de0b        About a minute ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ARG TEST=123                 0 B
f50f9524513f        9 months ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop) CMD ["/bin/bash"]             0 B
<missing>           9 months ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:b5391cb13172fb513d   125.1 MB
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As shown [in this issue](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/22436), this represents a [**build-arg**](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#/set-build-time-variables---build-arg) (ie the number of args used by to build the image)

> A good example is `http_proxy` or source versions for pulling intermediate files.
>   The `ARG` instruction lets `Dockerfile` authors define values that users can set at build-time using the `--build-arg` flag:

```
$ docker build --build-arg HTTP_PROXY=http://10.20.30.2:1234 .
```

> This flag allows you to pass the build-time variables that are accessed like regular environment variables in the RUN instruction of the Dockerfile.

---

> Here's an example of build args going through 1.10+:

```
[
  "|4 a=1 b=2 c=3 d=4 /bin/sh -c echo $a $b $c $d"
]
```

Comment: Thank you for that. Do you have any background on _why_ this is at all necessary or useful? Why does this not behave the same as for `ENV` variables (which don't seem to get the `|number` in the `history` output)? I have no practical application for understanding this, just satisfying my curiosity. But is there any practical application for having that `|number` there?

Comment: @SanderVerhagen it seems to represent the number of parameters used *at runtime*, as opposed to ENV, which persists in the image.

Comment: As you can see from the `history` output in the question, the `ARG` arguments also exist in the image.

Comment: @SanderVerhagen yes:once the ARG has been set (in the first intermediate image, it is repeated in the second intermediate image.