# What does "|1" or "|2" mean in a Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, dockerhub

I've come across this syntax on dockerhub. I'm trying to understand what it means and if it's part of the docker spec or something dockerhub has added.

Some examples:

```
|1 CONSUL_VERSION=1.15.4 /bin/sh -c addgroup consul && adduser -S -G consul consul
```

From https://hub.docker.com/layers/library/consul/1.15.4/images/sha256-d9142d9ce372de0fe99d1626bf9fb60374ac9478584eacaceba3229e76a7851b?context=explore

```
RUN |1 TARGETARCH=amd64 /bin/sh -c apt-mark hold ${NV_LIBCUBLAS_DEV_PACKAGE_NAME} ${NV_LIBNCCL_DEV_PACKAGE_NAME} # buildkit
```

From https://hub.docker.com/layers/runpod/stable-diffusion/web-automatic-8.0.3/images/sha256-110c9e2a885b959bf574f5460957f171f662db063bb94a3aa26925625b282ad1?context=explore

I've built these dockerfiles myself and playing around with the `|x` notation or removing it doesn't seem to have an effect. I can't find any reference to this notation in the official dockerfile docs. It's impossible to google for this string, and ChatGPT understands the question but doesn't know what it means.

Comment: The description of image layers does not use the syntax of the commands in the `Dockerfile`.

Answer (score 0):

Found a possible answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41312569/612702). Copy of the answer:

As shown [in this issue](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/22436), this represents a [**build-arg**](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#/set-build-time-variables---build-arg) (ie the number of args used by to build the image)

> A good example is `http_proxy` or source versions for pulling intermediate files.
> The `ARG` instruction lets `Dockerfile` authors define values that users can set at build-time using the `--build-arg` flag:

```
$ docker build --build-arg HTTP_PROXY=http://10.20.30.2:1234 .
```

> This flag allows you to pass the build-time variables that are accessed like regular environment variables in the RUN instruction of the Dockerfile.

---

> Here's an example of build args going through 1.10+:

```
[
  "|4 a=1 b=2 c=3 d=4 /bin/sh -c echo $a $b $c $d"
]
```